# How to duplicate the list of bit multiple times and its vice versa in Python

Tags: python, list, bit

I have a list of bit:

```
a = 00111001
```

And do the multiplication for the list:

```
multi = a * 3
```

It shows the result like this:

```
a = 001110010011100100111001
```

However, I need the result shows like this, which is each of the bit appear three times consecutively:

```
a = 0000001111111111000000111
```

In addition, how to convert `a = 0000001111111111000000111` to `a = 00111001` back?

I hope that anyone may help me. Thank you.

Comment: a=[0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1]
res=[[ele]*3 for ele in a]
print(res)....is it what you want...

Comment: Can you show what you actually have in `a`? Is it `[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]`, or something different? Because if you literally have `a = 00111001`, that's either octal for 37377 (Python 2.x), or a syntax error (3.x), not a list of bits. If you have `a = bitlist.BitList('00111001')` using some third-party library, you need to tell us what third party library. And so on.

Comment: @abarnert..Actually, it is `a = '00111001'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> a = '00111001'
>>> n=3
>>> ''.join(map(lambda x:x*3, a))
'000000111111111000000111'
```

Comment: How to do the vice versa..meaning that converting `a=000000111111...` to `a=00111001`?

Comment: `a.replace('0'*n, '0').replace('1'*n,'1')`

Comment: Did you mean `a.replace('000', '0').replace('111','1')`
All right, I got it.
Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

```
s = '00111001'
n = 3
''.join([s[i]*n for i in range(len(s))])
```

or more succinctly,

```
''.join(c*n for c in s)
```

but this assumes that your 'list of bit' is a string of characters that can be iterated over. If you have an actual number, then you can convert it into a string first, but you need to know how many binary digits you want in total in the case of leading zeros:

```
b = 57
bin(b)

'0b111001'

m = 8
s = '{b:>0{m}s}'.format(b=bin(b)[2:], m=m)
s

'00111001'

''.join([s[i]*n for i in range(len(s))])

'000000111111111000000111'
```

Comment: I will used the `''.join(c*n for c in s)`
Thank you.

Comment: @xnx..how to convert `a = 0000001111111111000000111` to `a = 00111001` back?